# In ArcGIS Online, how do I 'show related records' in the latest Map Viewer?

Tags: arcgis-online

In Map Viewer Classic, each feature had a link in its pop-up to "show related records," as shown on the bottom of this image:
[image]

Where do I find that in the new Map Viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pop-ups are configured in the classic map viewer, the related records can be seen in the new map viewer, but we do not have the option to configure in the new map viewer yet.

In the new map viewer, open the attribute table, and click on a feature, you should be able to see the related records in the table. the option is not there in the pop-ups.

**Additional info:**

Related records functionality is currently not available in Map Viewer, but is supposed to be added in Fall/Winter 2021 based on the roadmap shared below:

[Map Viewer Roadmap](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-documents/map-viewer-roadmap/ta-p/920839)

[image]

Find a few more reference links below:

- [Ability to add Related Records via Item Details Data tab](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-ideas/ability-to-add-related-records-via-item-details-data-tab/idi-p/939309)

Comment: Is the a 'relate' in the 'join or relate' sense, or something else?